# how to change div 'A' text color if div 'B' color has changed

Tags: jquery, css

I find a lot but didn't get any answer. My problem is, I have to change `btnPreviewTitle` text color if `buttonTitle` color has changed. `buttonTitle` color value is coming from `colorpicker` so i need to change color of `btnPreviewTitle` whenever `buttonTitle` color will change. here is my html

```
<div id="buttonTitle" style="float: left; color: rgb(43, 6, 6);">button text</div>

<div id="btnPreviewTitle">button text preview</div>
```

Comment: What js have you tried so far?

Comment: i didn't try anything yet. because i am confuse. i want to get something like "onchangestyle" event.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this  **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/299/)**

```
 $(this).on('input', function() { 
  var color = $('#colorpicker').val();
  $('#buttonTitle').css('color', color);

  if($('#buttonTitle').css('color') != 'rgb(43, 6, 6)') {
   $('#btnPreviewTitle').css('color', 'blue');
  }
});
```